# Opening slidedown in new tab with swagger

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, swagger

I'm having some issue editting code of [swagger-UI](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui).

My idea is, in swagger all the methods avaliable, if i click in then they open a "slidedown" content in jquery, and i want to change this to window.open or other code that really works and open the content in a new tab!

EDIT:

I want to change these [onclick state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdEAq.jpg) so that when I click it, a new tab is open.

Comment: It is unfortunately hard to understand your question.  Can you include a code example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just load a page that has nothing but the slider in it…

Comment: Its not working dude, I want to open the content in other tab, but i don't know how to import the data to another tab, im desperate.

My friend told me that is possible with JSon but i believe that is possible with javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/main/coffeescript/view/OperationView.coffee

Line 106 ff

There is the form validating. If the required fields fails you can open a new window.

In coffeescript you can open a new window with: window.open 'http://.......'

The form fields with values are stored in lines 126-139 and saved to map[field-name].

I would fork swagger-ui, make the changes and then build it (explained in swagger-ui readme) new. Then you can use it your way (copy the new files located in folder dist to your current swagger-ui folder)

Another idea: extend swagger-ui to set default-values for the required fields....then you always have one working option.

I hope this helps you.....(btw I am currently also tweaking a little bit some functions in swagger-ui..)